# I'm trying to alter one of my tables and adding a foreign key it I keep getting the same error

Tags: sql, sql-server

The error I get is:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
>   Foreign key 'fk_pid' references invalid column 'P_ID' in referencing table 'Detainee'.

My table structure:

```
create table Detainee
(
        D_ID           bigint primary key identity not null,
        Fname          nvarchar(50),
        Lname          nvarchar(50),
        Address        varchar(200),
        DateOfBirth    date,
        DateOfArrest   date,
        SourceOfArrest nvarchar(max)
);

create table PrisonCell
(
        P_ID     bigint primary key not null,
        Capacity int,
        RemCap   int,
        C_Type   varchar(20)
);
```

Code to alter table:

```
alter table Detainee 
    add constraint fk_pid foreign key(P_ID) references PrisonCell(P_ID)
```

Comment: Your code cannot generate that error.  It has no foreign key definitions.  You should update the question and provide the code that generates the error.  But based on the error, it is just a type -- `P_ID` versus `D_ID`.

Comment: alter table Detainee
add constraint fk_pid foreign key(P_ID) references PrisonCell(P_ID)                                 didn't notice not posting this.. how can i update my question i'm stll new here

Comment: There is an Edit button under your question.

Comment: You first need to add column `P_ID` in `Detainee` table before executing this alter command.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

- **add the column** `P_ID BIGINT` to your table `Detainee`
- **then** add the FK constraint to that column

Just adding the FK constraint to the table isn't going to automagically add a column as well...

You should be able to do this in a single step:

```
ALTER TABLE Detainee 
    ADD P_ID BIGINT 
    CONSTRAINT fk_pid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PrisonCell(P_ID);
```